# Validate Scala case class at compile time

Tags: scala, apache-spark, case-class, scala-2.11

I have case classes in a Scala 2.11 app that have a method that relies on the names of the fields of the case class like this:

```scala
final case class Foo(
  val a: String,
  val b: String,
  val c: String
) {
  def partitionColumns: Seq[String] = Seq("b", "c")
}
```

I want a compile-time check to throw an error if one of the `partitionColumns` doesn't exist as a field on the case class, for example something that will catch this:

```
final case class Bar(
  val a: String,
  val b: String,
  val c: String
) {
  def partitionColumns: Seq[String] = Seq("x", "y")
}
```

So far, I've encapsulated the partitioning behavior in a trait, which reduces the number of times/places that this can go wrong:

```scala
sealed trait partitionedByBAndC {
  def b: String
  def c: String
  def partitionColumns: Seq[String] = Seq("b", "c")
}

final case class Foo(
  val a: String,
  val b: String,
  val c: String
) extends PartitionedByBAndC
```

But if the trait is written incorrectly, there's no check e.g. this code, which compiles fine:

```scala
sealed trait partitionedByBAndCIncorrect {
  def b: String
  def c: String
  def partitionColumns: Seq[String] = Seq("x", "y")
}

final case class Foo(
  val a: String,
  val b: String,
  val c: String
) extends partitionedByBAndCIncorrect
```

In Scala 2.13, I might be able to use [productElementNames](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Product.html#productElementNames:Iterator[String]), but I'm on Scala 2.11 (and Spark 2.3). I'm not sure what to do without actually constructing an object out of the class/trait, which seems like a lot of overhead (considering there are many of these traits in the code).

Comment: Why would you have these fields?

Comment: For writing data out to a partitioned hive table.

Comment: OK, and have you tried to use reflection?

Comment: I haven't, I'm not so familiar with it. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a small library ([scala-nameOf)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.dwickern/scala-nameof_2.11/1.0.3) which can be used to do this:

```
final case class Foo(
                    val a: String,
                    val b: String,
                    val c: String
                  ) {
import com.github.dwickern.macros.NameOf._
def partitionColumns: Seq[String] = Seq(nameOf(this.a),nameOf(this.b))
```

}

This won't compile for fields which are not part of the case class

Comment: Thanks, that works great. In Scala 2.13 there's also `productElementNames` which would work as well.